# Qt Qml tree model menu with translations

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-linguist

I am trying to make an app with live translation of text in a large tree model menu structure, in the same manner as: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/itemviews/simpletreemodel?h=5.15

The item's "data" is a QString that is translated like

```
root = new MenuObject(tr("Main menu"));
```

And children are appended like:

```
root->appendChild(new MenuObject(tr("Test 1")))
    .appendChild(new MenuObject(tr("Test 2")))
```

I am using QML to show these, with a qmllistpoprerty to show these menus like:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<MenuObject> list READ getList NOTIFY listChanged);
```

The QML is a simple ListView with a delegate Label showing the MenuObjects's description with the q_property:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString description READ getDescription CONSTANT);
```

To change language i am using a function getting the translation file into the translator, followed by:

```
installTranslator(translator);
engine.retranslate();
```

Now this does work for simple q_properties like:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString header READ getHeader NOTIFY listChanged);
```

Where

```
QString MainMenu::getHeader(){
    return tr("Header");
}
```

But I CANNOT get the translations to work for the items in the treemodel. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a model instead of `QQmlListProperty`? Models initially support data changing handling etc.

Comment: The problem is not with changing the data. The problem is with translating whatever is in it to different languages on the fly.

Comment: Also i did try with just a MenuObject exposed as a q_property directly without the text changing upon retranslating with qmlengine.

Answer (score 1):

If your `description` prop never fires an updated signal, then your UI will never refresh it.

The reason it works for `Q_PROPERTY(QString header READ getHeader NOTIFY listChanged);` is because presumably the `listChanged()` signal is fired whenever `header` is supposed to change also.

To fix it, you need to declare an appropriate `NOTIFY` signal for your `description`, and of course it is no longer a `CONSTANT`.

Comment: You are saying that the MenuObject's Qproperty should be redone as:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString description READ getDescription NOTIFY descriptionChanged);

But what triggers the notify? I tried hooking this up to the translators emitted signal "languageChanged", and it does do the notify, but alas the text is not translated.